# What is the meaning of the acronym מה"ט?

Tags: talmud-gemara

FOr example in
מגדל עוז שבת י״ב:ב׳
ומה״ט נמי ניחא סוגיין דפ׳ מילה גמרא

ט"ז על אורח חיים תצח
האי ביום שני אין לו ביאור דאפילו ביום טוב ראשון שרי מה"ט ותו מאי מעליותא דהביאום מערב דהיינו בי"ט ראשון והנה דברים אלו נתייחסו בר"י בשם א"ח בשם הרשב"א

Answer (score 3):

It is מהאי טעמא - "From this reason"

Answer (score 3):

[Yad Meir](http://www.yadmeir.co.il/?CategoryID=343&ArticleID=928) has a dictionary of abbreviations and writes

> מה"ט – מהאי טעמא

which means “from this reason”.

A longer quote from the Migdal Oz reads,

> והיינו נמי טעמא דשרו ביוה"כ לכ"ג משום דקי"ל דאין שבות במקדש והם אמרו
> והם אמרו ושרו אפילו דר' יהודה משום מצוה וכן פירשו ר"י הזקן ורבותינו
> בעלי התוס' ז"ל **מה"ט** נמי ניחא סוגיין דפ' מילה
>
> And that is also the reason that they allowed on Yom Kippur for the
> Kohen Godol, because we hold that Rabbinical prohibitions do not apply
> in the Beis Hamikdosh ….... and the R”i Hazoken and the Tosafists also
> explained in this way and **from this reason** it fits with the
> passage about miloh.

This seems to fit.